# Optimizing function to fix the headers of the html tables, with different widths depending on the size of the screen and content in realtime

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I developed a function to fix the header of html tables, responsive tables with bootstrap 4, with different widths depending on the size of the screen and the content inside "td" in realtime.

First I call the function on the responsive tables

```
$('.table-responsive:has("table.fixed-header")').on('scroll', function () {
        fixeTableHeader(parseInt($(this).offset().top));
    });
```

Then the function starts the script

```
function fixeTableHeader(top) {

        var thSize = [];
        var tdSize = [];
        var tablePosition = parseInt($('.fixed-header').offset().top);


        $('.fixed-header tbody tr:has(td) > *').each(function (index, val) {
            tdSize[index] = $(this).width();
        });

        $('.fixed-header thead th').each(function (index, val) {
            thSize[index] = $(this).width();
        });

        if (top > tablePosition) {
            $('.fixed-header thead').stop().css({
                top: (top - tablePosition),
                left: 0,
                position: 'absolute'
            });
            $('.fixed-header thead th').each(function (index, val) {
                $(this).width(thSize[index]);
            });

            var tdLength = $('.fixed-header tbody tr:has(td):eq(0) > *').length;
            if (tdLength > Object.keys(thSize).length) {
                $('.fixed-header tbody tr:has(td):eq(0) > *').each(function (index, val) {
                    if ($(this).width() == tdSize[index]) {
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        $('.fixed-header tbody tr:has(td) > *').each(function (index, val) {
                            $(this).width(tdSize[index]);
                        });
                        return false;
                    }

                });
            }

        } else {
            $('.fixed-header thead').css({top: 0, left: 0, position: 'static'});
        }
}
```

HTML EX:

```
<div class="table-responsive border border-top-0">
  <table class="table table-striped mb-0 fixed-header">
    <thead>
        <tr>
           <th></th>
           <th></th>
           <th></th>
           <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
   </tr>
   ...
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

Everything works fine except that if there are several html tables on the same page the browser is extremely slow!

Can you help me optimize my function so that it works properly in all situations?

Comment: You have to time each part to see where the problem is. The problem probably is related to long selectors like `'.fixed-header tbody tr:has(td):eq(0) > *'`. Please include the HTML part, so we can test it and propose a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are three functions to fix an html table head in any condition!

```
       function setCookie(name, value, days) {
            var expires = "";
            if (days) {
                var date = new Date();
                date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
                expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
            }
            document.cookie = name + "=" + (value || "") + expires + "; path=/";
        }

        function getCookie(name) {
            var nameEQ = name + "=";
            var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
                var c = ca[i];
                while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
                if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
            }
            return null;
        }   

        function fixeTableHeader(topAdd = 0, otherTop = 0) {

                var $fixedHeader = $('.fixed-header');
                if ($fixedHeader.length) {

                    var $thead;
                    var changeSize = false;
                    var thSize = [];
                    var top = otherTop === 0 ? $(window).scrollTop() + topAdd : otherTop;
                    var tablePosition = parseInt($fixedHeader.offset().top);
                    var tableHeight = parseInt($fixedHeader.height());

                    //Check table's header cloned
                    if (!$fixedHeader.hasClass('cloned')) {
                        $fixedHeader.addClass('cloned');
                        $thead = $('.fixed-header thead').clone().insertAfter('.fixed-header thead').addClass('clonedHead').hide();
                    } else {
                        $thead = $('.fixed-header.cloned thead.clonedHead');
                    }

                    //Responsive : recalculate the width
                    if (!getCookie('screenDim') || getCookie('screenDim') !== $fixedHeader.width()) {
                        setCookie('screenDim', $('.fixed-header').width());

                        changeSize = true;

                        $('.fixed-header thead th').each(function (index, val) {
                            thSize[index] = $(this).width();
                        });

                        $('th', $thead).each(function (index, val) {
                            $(this).width(thSize[index]);
                        });
                    }

                    //Check if cloned header is needed
                    if (tableHeight && top > tablePosition && (top - tablePosition < tableHeight)) {

                        if (changeSize) {
                            $('th', $thead).each(function (index, val) {
                                $(this).width(thSize[index]);
                            });
                        }

                        $thead.stop().css({
                            top: (top - tablePosition),
                            left: 0,
                            position: 'absolute'
                        });

                        if ($thead.is(":hidden")) {
                            $thead.show();
                        }

                    } else {
                        $thead.hide().css({top: 0, left: 0, position: 'static'});
                    }
                }
            }
```

Just add the class "fixed-header" to your table then :

if you working with a responsive table (Bootstrap 4) so use :

```
$('.table-responsive').scroll(function () {
    fixeTableHeader(0, $(this).offset().top);
});
```

otherwise it will be enough

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    fixeTableHeader(); // if you have a fixed nav on document : add $('#navbar').outerHeight() as parameter
});
```

Enjoy !